# Microsoft Azure Service Bus Queue working as FIFO

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm developing two WebJobs for azure: One which will be putting messages in the Service Bus Queue using a topic and another which is subscribed to the ServiceBusTrigger using the same topic.

The messages are sent to the service bus queue correctly but when run the WebJob subscribed to the ServiceBusTrigger those messages are not being processed in FIFO basis.

The code for the WebJob which puts messages in the service bus queue is the following:

```
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.Create();

// Delete if exists
if (namespaceManager.TopicExists("SampleTopic"))
{
    namespaceManager.DeleteTopic("SampleTopic");
}

TopicDescription td = new TopicDescription("SampleTopic");
td.SupportOrdering = true;
TopicDescription myTopic = namespaceManager.CreateTopic(td);

SubscriptionDescription myAuditSubscription = namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(myTopic.Path, "ImporterSubscription");

TopicClient topicClient = TopicClient.Create("SampleTopic");
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var message = new BrokeredMessage("message"+i);                   
    topicClient.Send(message);
}
topicClient.Close();
```

The WebJob which is subscrited to the service bus trigger has the following code:

```
namespace HO.Importer.Azure.WebJob.TGZProcessor
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.UseServiceBus();
            JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }

        public static void WriteLog([ServiceBusTrigger("SampleTopic", "ImporterSubscription")] string message,
            TextWriter logger)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(message));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve to process the messages fromo the queue as FIFO?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Azure Service Bus provides FIFO feature(Sessions), it is better not to assume this kind of behavior with a broker based queuing system. Ben Morris had a good post [Don’t assume message ordering in Azure Service Bus](http://www.ben-morris.com/dont-assume-message-ordering-in-azure-service-bus/) on the fact that assuming ordering with asynchronous messaging is almost a fallacy and reasons for that.

Comment: Thanks! What I need to do is to process blobs as they are being uploaded to a container. One of the requisites is that they need to be processed in the order as they arrive to the blob so I thought that notifying a service bus queue which is set to support ordering would solve the problem.

Comment: Depending on how blobs arrive, you could build a custom logic to achieve this. If you know for sure blobs come in order, why not to have a blob trigger instead?

Comment: Is the linked article still valid? As the solution by @chinsscope points out, `sessionId` can be used to ensure message ordering. The article claims that this isn't enough, but the Azure Docs explicitly state: *A receiver cannot have two messages concurrently "in flight," but the messages must be processed in order. A new message can only be obtained when the prior message has been completed or dead-lettered. Abandoning a message causes the same message to be served again with the next receive operation.*

Comment: It's a link, you should be able to open it. And yes, with sessions one will get the desired FIFO behavior but not the same scale-out. With FIFO, messages are processed in a serial manner, *per session*. That's a big drop back for systems that expect to be able to handle large loads of messages. Otherwise, it's an option. My recommendation is *always* question if order is required and only when it's a must, apply it.

Answer (score 6):

Use SessionId or PartitionKey, that will ensure the message is handled by the same message broker.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning

"SessionId: If a message has the BrokeredMessage.SessionId property set, then Service Bus uses this property as the partition key. This way, all messages that belong to the same session are handled by the same message broker. This enables Service Bus to guarantee message ordering as well as the consistency of session states."

Comment: Specifying the sessionId solved my problem. It is now in FIFO manner.