# Messages ordering when receiving batch of messages from Service Bus

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm receiving messages in batch from Azure Service Bus:

```
IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> receivedMessages = await serviceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(maxMessages: maxMessages, maxWaitTime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

It works fine but I am unsure if it also consider the ordering (FIFO). I know what we can achieve this behaviour using Sessions. But I want to ask if I need to use sessions when receiving batch of messages?

I've a single receiver that receives and process messages in batches. But I want to ensure ordering as I am receiving devices info e.g last seen etc and I need to make sure that I've updated the correct info.

Also if Sessions is the only way then should I just set the SessionId to DeviceId and that will make sure that the all the messages linked to a single device get processed in order?

**Update**

I've done a quick test and I can see that message are received in sequence.
I've added batch of 150 messages to the topic:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfMessages; i++)
{
    // try adding a message to the batch
    var msg = new ServiceBusMessage($"Message {i}");
    msg.ApplicationProperties.Add("Type", 1);
    if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(msg))
    {
        // if it is too large for the batch
        throw new Exception($"The message {i} is too large to fit in the batch.");
    }
}

try
{
    
    await sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"A batch of {numOfMessages} messages has been published.");
    
}
finally
{
    // Calling DisposeAsync on client types is required to ensure that network
    // resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.
    await sender.DisposeAsync();
    await client.DisposeAsync();
}
```

After this I added a receiver method that receives and logs the message to the console:

```
private async Task ProcessMessages(int maxMessagesToProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    
     while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         var receivedMessageList = new List<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>();
         IReadOnlyList<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> receivedMessages = await _serviceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(maxMessages: maxMessagesToProcess, maxWaitTime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
         if (receivedMessages.Count > 0)
         {
             receivedMessageList.AddRange(receivedMessages);
             foreach (var msg in receivedMessageList)
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine($"Message: {msg.Body}");
             }
             if (receivedMessageList.Count >= ConcurrentMessagesToProcess)
             {
                 //await ProcessReceivedMessages(receivedMessageList);

                 var processAgain = await CheckForMessageProcessing();
                 if (!processAgain)
                 {
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

After multiple tests, I get the messages in sequence. I'm unsure if I've missed any scenario or is this expected.

Comment: I can see [`SessionId` and `PartitionKey` properties inside `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage?view=azure-dotnet#properties),  [Use SessionId or PartitionKey, that will ensure the message is handled by the same message broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472294/microsoft-azure-service-bus-queue-working-as-fifo).

Comment: Sure, but I've only got a single receiver.

Comment: Which are you trying to do - work with guaranteed behaviour or do what seems to currently work? Because if you want guaranteed behaviour, go with what the documentation says, not what any particular experiments you have performed seem to produce.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the only problem I would have is when a single device has multiple messages in the topic and I want to process them in sequence. Otherwise I don't mind the ordering (if Device10 gets processed before Device5). Also with the ServiceBusReceiver, I receive a batch of 500 messages and process them in bulk. But seems like by using await _client.AcceptNextSession() will process all session one by one which will be a costly operation. I need a better way to process session enabled messages in bulk.

Comment: Or may be I can use the same session id for all messages and then receiver batch from ServiceBusSessionReceiver and that will make sure that the session has processed the messages in order.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) on Azure Service Bus message sessions, achieving a first-in, first-out (FIFO) pattern involves using sessions to ensure that messages are processed in the order they were received.

- When submitting messages into a queue or topic, ensure that each message is assigned a session ID. This [session ID](https://i.imgur.com/B7nRv1P.png) acts as an application-defined identifier unique to the session.
- On session-aware queues or subscriptions, sessions are initiated when there's at least one message with a session ID. Messages with the same session ID are grouped together, forming a session.
- When multiple messages are sent with session IDs, Service Bus ensures that messages within each session are processed in the order they were received. This maintains the FIFO guarantee, as messages within the same session are processed sequentially.
- To receive bulk messages, use Batching. Batching delivers a set number of messages to the function as a single batch, allowing for processing multiple messages in one invocation.
- The below sample is to receive and process messages from an Azure Service Bus queue using the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` library, the session state is retrieved using `GetSessionStateAsync()`.

References Used:

- Service Bus Batching and [Pre-Fetch](https://pmichaels.net/2021/04/03/service-bus-batching-and-pre-fetch/).
- Sending and receiving session [messages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample03_SendReceiveSessions.md#sending-and-receiving-session-messages).

```
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
        string queueName = "<queue_name>";
        int batchSize = 10; // Number of messages to receive in each batch
        int prefetchCount = 100; // Number of messages to prefetch

        await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        var receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
        {
            PrefetchCount = prefetchCount
        });

        var sessionReceiver = await client.AcceptNextSessionAsync(queueName);

        while (true)
        {
            var messages = await sessionReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(batchSize);

            if (messages == null || messages.Count == 0)
                break;

            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                // Process the received message
                string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {messageBody} ,SequenceNumber={message.SequenceNumber}, SessionId= {message.SessionId}");

                // Simulate processing of the message
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                // Complete the message
                await sessionReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
            }
        }

        // After processing all messages, retrieve session state
        BinaryData state = await sessionReceiver.GetSessionStateAsync();
      

        await sessionReceiver.CloseAsync();
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However I noticed that when I receive messages in batch, it always get processed in sequence. I tried it multiple times and the results were same. So I am confused if I need sessions or not.

Comment: @ASK AFAIK as per documentation we need sessions .

Comment: I've updated my questions and added the code chunk which I'd tried.